# Autolayout constraints for leading edges

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I have 3 UIViews -- view1, view2, view3. I set the constraints in storyboard as follows:

1. view1.leading = safeArea.leading + 0 (constraint1 as IBOutlet),
2. view2.leading = view1.leading,
3. view3.leading = view2.leading

Next, I change constant in constraint1 in code. I expect view1, view2, view3 to automatically realign as view1.leading is changed. But instead I get autolayout errors:

```
 [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
 (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283317a70 UIView:0x10321f7d0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x28290ddc0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283316bc0 UIView:0x10321f7d0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x28290ddc0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading + 5   (active)>"
 )

  Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
   <NSLayoutConstraint:0x283316bc0 UIView:0x10321f7d0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x28290ddc0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading + 5   (active)>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the constraints and how you changed the constant for that constraint. It seems like another constraint was added.

Comment: constraint1.constant = 5

Comment: Can you share the relevant code which shows when and how they are called?

Comment: That error looks like you have 2 leading constraints on view1 and one of them now had a constant of 5.

Comment: Let me share screenshots from Storyboard.

Comment: @darrenallen7 You were right, I found spurious constraints when I took screenshots of each and every constrait on the view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding comment as an answer to make it easier for others searching*

That error looks like you have 2 leading constraints on `view1` and one of them now had a constant of 5.